# Showing a view (Panel, container etc.) after clicking on a google marker in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch, extjs, google-maps-markers

I have a map on sencha touch 2 that is loaded with markers (dynamically). Currently, when i click on the markers, their respective infowindow opens. I want to have container opened using a button in the infowindow, or by clicking on the marker.

Is this possible and can anyone guide me along? I only know it has something to do with the marker's listener...

Answer (score 1):

In order to listen the click event for a marker you can use the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', onClickHandler);
```

marker is a google.maps.Marker.

If you want to put a button inside of infoWindow. You could listen for click events in the infoWindow and then check if the click was inside a button.

```
....
infoWindow.content = '<div>text</div><div class="button">button</div>';
infoWindow.content.addEventListener('click', onInfoWindowClickHandler);

function onInfoWindowClickHanlder(event) {
   if(event.target.className == 'button') {
      // Button click
   }
}
```

This is only one aproximation. I've not tested the code, so could need some tunning, but the idea should work.

You must read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/